# Should we correct grammar in code

Tags: support, edits

I have come across a lot of new users posting code that does not follow naming conventions. For example code like

```
public class myclass{
int myint;
String myimportantword;
void method dothisreallycomplicatedprocess(){}
}
```

As you can see, the code is hard to read.

Should we just auto correct it?

or

Should we post a comment letting the user know what the naming conventions are?

Comment: Doesn't follow the naming conventions of who? Unless I specifically asked or was being paid to code in a certain way, I wouldn't want my coding style changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well...

**If it's code in a question, leave it.**  That's their convention, but you can point out the appropriate conventions in a comment, or even in an answer to their question.

**If it's code in an answer, it depends.**  If you're only modifying the answer to be more readable with respect to modern Java conventions, and you **don't change any of the logic itself**, then it's an edit I'd be okay with.  Although, I'd also *strongly* encourage you to find more stuff to edit, too.

**If the code is the only thing you edit...please don't.**  If there are other glaring typos in the actual answer, then fix those too.

Comment: Suggesting an edit to an answer correcting code is usually rejected as "invalid edit". It's generally better to not make people review things that require domain-specific knowledge.